# Trace for function name from the output of cuda-memcheck

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu, memcheck

I'm running to `cuda-memcheck` to debug my code and the output is as follows

```
========= Program hit cudaErrorCudartUnloading (error 29) due to "driver shutting down" on CUDA API call to cudaFree. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x2e40d3]
=========     Host Frame:./nmt [0x53526]
=========     Host Frame:./nmt [0xfbd9]
terminate called after throwing an instance of '=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0x3c259]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0x3c2a5]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfc) [0x21ecc]
thrust::system::system_error'
=========     Host Frame:./nmt [0x530a]
=========
  what():  driver shutting down
========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
========= Internal error (20)
========= No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found
```

Is it possible to tell from the line `Host Frame:./nmt [0x53526]` where is broken in the code? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/#stack-backtraces

Comment: That's a great resource. Thank you @talonmies

Comment: Yeah, when in doubt, read the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @talonmies indicated (I suspect he will not mind if I post a CW answer), the `cuda-memcheck` tool provides additional stack back tracing capability, which can be enabled with the `--show-backtrace` switch added to the command line.

The back trace may consist of both host and device functions (i.e. host and device back traces.)

If the application has been also compiled with host debug symbol information (e.g. `-g` on linux) then `cuda-memcheck` can show function names for the host functions in the host backtrace.

Additional usage information is available in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/#stack-backtraces).

Answer (score 1):

For me `cuda-memcheck` with different sub-tools such as `memcheck`, `racecheck`, `initcheck` and `synccheck` often produces host backtraces without the line numbers or even without the host functions mentioned. Searching on the internet only shows this question, but I already pass `-g` or even `-g3` to the host compiler, and `--show-backtrace` flag to `cuda-memcheck` is said in the docs to be `yes` by default (passing it explicitly doesn't help). So I do the following with the backtrace:

Consider your compiled program is called `a.out` and you get a line in the host backtrace like `Host Frame:./nmt [0x530a]`. Then open your program in `cuda-gdb` with:

```
cuda-gdb a.out
```

Then, let your program load all the shared libraries (at least up to a point in `main()` function). Enter the following in `cuda-gdb` prompt:

```
b main
r
```

Then, look up the function name with:

```
info symbol 0x530a
```

Or look up the line number with:

```
info line *0x530a
```

Where `0x530a` is the address `cuda-memcheck` printed for you. I guess NVIDIA could automate this easily (as well as demangling the host function names where they are printed).